# How to show constructor declaration with Visual studio 2012?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

When I hover my cursor on a function called in my code in Visual studio 2012, a small box pops up to show its declaration. How let this work for constructors?

```
Function(1, 2); // Hover on Function
MyClass a(1, 2); // Hover on a or MyClass or use any shortcut key
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Might try closing the solution and deleting the `.sdf` file.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Does it show the constructor arguments' name and type?

Comment: Yes, even for templates.

Comment: If VS2012 doesn't do it, there are extensions that do. Visual Assist X comes to mind. At the very least, you can erase the beginning bracket and put it back in to see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is C++'s syntax for constructor calls. It works fine with normal methods because they look like method calls. Constructor calls are all mixed up with the object declaration, and when you hover over them, VS just gives you a tooltip with the object's declaration because it assumes that's what you want.

[image]

Hovering over the text gets you the same tooltip as if you had invoked the "Display Quick Info" command (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>).

But there is also the "Display Parameter Info" command, invoked with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, that will display the information you're interested in for constructors.

[image]

The trick is that you have to invoke the command with the caret *inside* of the parentheses. It won't work when the caret is somewhere within the identifier.